# Doctrine said I should split parameter in explicit fields but then my ID is empty

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm using a third party software which neither using Symfony nor Doctrine nor something else. Only PHP & MySQL.

And now I tried to generate entities from this old MySQL structure and using them into my project.
But I don't understand this double primary key situation.

I should split the parameter in explicit field and bind them separately... But in the doctrine documentation it seems possible, too. So what they want? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-2-simple-derived-identity

```
/** @Id @OneToOne(targetEntity="User") */
```

This is the error message I get.

```
[Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException]
Binding an entity with a composite primary key to a query is not supported.
You should split the parameter into the explicit fields and bind them separately.
```

And this is my first entity:

**src/ShMaBundle/Entity/Passage.php**

```
<?php
// src/ShMaBundle/Entity/Passage.php
namespace ShMaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Passage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="passage", @ORM\Index(name="IDX_98AF07F7EC91F2AA", columns={"DcplID"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Passage
{
    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="PositionsIdx", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $positionsidx;

    /**
     * @var Discipline
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Discipline")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="DcplID", referencedColumnName="DcplID")
     * })
     */
    private $dcplid;
}
```

And this is my second entity.

**src/ShMaBundle/Entity/Discipline.php**

```
<?php
// src/ShMaBundle/Entity/Discipline.php
namespace ShMaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Discipline
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="discipline")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Discipline
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="DcplID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $dcplid;
}
```

And year I don't know why doctrine can't load the entity and ignoring everything else. I can access the id by `$passage->dcplid->dcplid`. Or they want that I do it more better. Having something like this.

```
<?php
// src/ShMaBundle/Entity/Passage.php
namespace ShMaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Passage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="passage", @ORM\Index(name="IDX_98AF07F7EC91F2AA", columns={"DcplID"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Passage
{
    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="PositionsIdx", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $positionsidx;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $dcplid;

    /**
     * @var Discipline
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Discipline")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="DcplID", referencedColumnName="DcplID")
     * })
     */
    private $dcpl;
}
```

Then I can access the discipline and the id separately.
But if I test this then I have an empty dcplid. But the $dcpl works and is filled. Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, merge the oneToOne tables into one single table. 
You should also use better attribute names like :

```
/**
 * Passage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="passage", @ORM\Index(name="IDX_98AF07F7EC91F2AA", columns={"DcplID"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Passage
{
    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="PositionsIdx", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $positionsidx;

    /**
     * @var Discipline
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Discipline")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="DcplID", referencedColumnName="DcplID")
     * })
 */
    private $discipline;

public function getDiscipline(){
  return $this->discipline;
}
}
```

When do you have this error, on a query ? 
Why don't you have any getter and setter methods ? 
You should use a getter : `$passage->getDiscipline()`
Then, you can access the Id of the discipline

EDIT : 
In the class `Passage` : 
You have to remove the following :

```
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
```

that is over the attribute :

```
 private $dcplid
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But no I cant merge the tables because its a running system without symfony / doctrine / something else. And I'm using getters and setters in the real file - but I think this is not important for the solution, if you see a lot of `public function getSomething() { return $this->something; }`. Or do you need it? The question is why the one to one is not working if I add the `@ORM\Id` annotation? :-(

Comment: I added some precisions. The solution was already in the answer ^^